# Why is it that Not All PDF, PPT and Word Can be Quick Viewed by Google?

Tags: google-search

I am very glad when [Google adds quick view to its search function](http://mashable.com/2009/10/07/google-search-results-pdfs/). However, I found that not all of the PDFs, PPTs, Xls, Docs can be quick viewed. Any idea why this is so?

Answer (score 3):

Google is slowly rolling out the feature for all the documents, currently you will see about 50% of the indexed documents have this feature. If you are using Firefox, you could install Greasemonkey and use [the script](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/59557) to view all the documents in Google Docs. Works perfectly...

Answer (score 0):

Two suppositions (replace below pdf by ppt/xls/doc as needed):

1. The Google pdf-to-html converter failed on this PDF file.
2. The PDF file is still waiting in some Google queue to be converted.